# _.template is not a function

Tags: jsp, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have problem when adding async script tag in my jsp. I use backbone.js and underscore js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js?v=${ss}"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.string.min.js?v=${ss}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js?v=${ss}"></scrip>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js?v=${ss}"></scrip>
```

When i add snippet:

```
 <script async
    id="moduleScript"
    src="${src}"
    data-container-id="containerId"
    data-api-key="${apiKey}"
    data-api-token="${apiToken}"
    data-lang="en" 
    data-after-init-callback="initialized()">
</script>
```

my underscore.js somehow gets broken and throws "Uncaught TypeError: _.template is not a function" or _.each is not a function. Also src atribute is .js that use this libs:

- bootstrap-datepicker
- jquery-bootgrid
- moment.js

please help. Thx

UPDATE: app.js

```
var render = function(tmpl_name, tmpl_data) { //tmpl_name = "moderator/advisor-tooltip", tmpl_data = Object {model: child}
    if ( !render.tmpl_cache ) { 
        render.tmpl_cache = {};
    }

if ( !render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] ) {//tmpl_name = "moderator/advisor-tooltip"
    var tmpl_dir = 'templates'; //tmpl_dir = "templates"
    var tmpl_url = tmpl_dir + '/' + tmpl_name + '.html'; //tmpl_url = "templates/moderator/advisor-tooltip.html", tmpl_name = "moderator/advisor-tooltip"

    var tmpl_string;
    $.ajax({
        url: tmpl_url,
        method: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            tmpl_string = data; //tmpl_string = "↵<% var advisor = model.toJSON() %>↵↵<b><%=advisor.name %></b><br />↵<b class="advisorToolTipCodeSize">CODE: <%=advisor.codes %></b>↵<b
        }
    });
    render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] = _.template(tmpl_string);// brake point -> Uncaught TypeError: _.template is not a function
}

return render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name](tmpl_data); 
};
```

**Requests for js:**
[image: requests]

Comment: Where do you get this error message? Can you post the `console.log` error?

Comment: @SimoEndre Updated question

Comment: I think you over complicate the problem. This is not the normal way to populate the template variables with concrete values. The second thing is that your `tmpl_string` is not correct.

Comment: why dou you think its not correct?

Comment: You are using javascript variables inside the template, which is not quite correct. You have to populate the html template variables with values coming from backbone models.